# DateChooser date other then Gregorian date

Tags: gwt, calendar, smartgwt, smartgwt-pro

[image]

I want to know how can I implement a date chooser in SmartGWT to show other dates for example: chinese,perisan,arabic dates. Any code or link to some site will be appreciated. I tried searching SmartGWT forum but could not find any help.

I went a step further by doing some work and managed to go one step in the front. What I did is I used a Persian calendar and set it in this method like this:

```
dateChooser.setData(CommonUtil.gregorianToJalali(new Date()));
```

But don't know how to change those other things. Please help get it working

Here is the full code:

```
public class DateChooserSample extends VLayout{



public DateChooserSample() {
    init();
}

public void init() {

    setShowEdges(true);   
    setWidth(150);   
    setMembersMargin(5);   
    setLayoutMargin(10);   


    DynamicForm form = new DynamicForm();   
    form.setWidth(300);   
    final BlurbItem blurbItem = new BlurbItem();   
    form.setItems(blurbItem);   

    final DateChooser dateChooser = new DateChooser();   
    dateChooser.setData(CommonUtil.gregorianToJalali(new Date()));
    dateChooser.setWidth(100);   

    blurbItem.setValue("Current date : " + CommonUtil.gregorianToJalali(new Date()));   
    dateChooser.addDataChangedHandler(new DataChangedHandler() {   
        @Override  
        public void onDataChanged(DataChangedEvent event) {   
            blurbItem.setValue("Selected date : " + CommonUtil.gregorianToJalali(dateChooser.getData()));   
        }   
    });   



    addMember(dateChooser);   
    addMember(form);   

}

}
```

Comment: JUST FYI - ECMA Script i.e javascript i.e GWT has a bug related to gregorian dates like persian calendar related to Feb 29.